# Knockout JS to update view model from ajax success that can be call outside of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Here I have define self.fromDate = ko.observable() and self.toDate = ko.observable() now this value is set when click event of button in function is call with ajax request. On success ajax call need to set values to these two view model. And set value must be accessible outside of ajax success function as well

```
var app = function(){
   self.fromDate = ko.observable();
   self.toDate = ko.observable();
   self.setThisYear = function(){
      $.getJSON("/Dashboard/GetFiscalYearDetails", function (data) {
            self.fromDate(data.fromDate);
            self.toDate(data.toDate);
            console.log(self.fromDate()); //set data
            console.log(self.toDate());   //set date
      }
      console.log(self.fromDate()); //undefined
      console.log(self.toDate());   //undefined
   }
}
ko.applyBindings(new app());

<a href="#" data-bind="click: setThisYear">This Year</a>
```

Comment: the outer calls to `console.log` returns `undefined` because they happen before the inner calls (Ajax is asynchronous). So you're setting the values just fine. Is there something else you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to set value of variable of self.toDate() and self.fromDate() to use in other function as well.

Comment: Well, you're setting them just fine. The other function that needs to use them should be called after the ajax is finished, so just call it inside your callback function (i.e., inside `function (data)`).

Answer (score 0):

This maybe wrong but it looks you are just missing one essential thing:

defining `self`

```
var app = function(){
    var self = this;
    ...
```

also there is syntax errors like `$.getJSON(` never gets closed

you should use the browser console to determine errors, also you can assign the vm to a variable itself, like:

```
 var system = ko.applyBindings(new app());
```

in console or any followed scripts you could then just type

```
system.fromDate()
```

to retrieve the current observable value, or:

```
system.fromDate("123")
```

to set the value